# angular ui bootstrap tooltip hidden

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

The sidebar in my application is as follows

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li>
             <a uib-tooltip='Home' tooltip-placement="right" href="/home" 
                data-icon="j" class="icon" ></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="page-content-wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

The css is as follows

```
      .sidebar-wrapper{
        position:fixed;
    }

    sidebar-nav{
      position:absolute;
    }

    .wrapper{
      position: relative;
   }
  .page-content-wrapper{
   position: relative;
  }
```

When I use angular bootstrap tool-tip it seems to be hidden under the the sidebar-wrapper when I set tried the following

```
.tooltip{
  @extend .tooltip;
  z-index: 1000 !important;
}
```

it still does not seem to work.

Note: when I use placement as bottom the tool tip appears below but placement right has this issue.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this on jsfiddle?

Comment: have you tried using `tooltip-append-to-body`

Comment: thanks it worked like a charm

Comment: then if you don't mind, post the answer for future visitors

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @svarog it saved me

by adding this html attribute everthing works like a charm!

```
tooltip-append-to-body="true"


<span  class="fa fa-refresh btn-refresh"  ng-click="restoreUserPreferences(subtable)" uib-tooltip="{{'restore.user.preferences' | translate }}" tooltip-append-to-body="true">
```